# ¿Como pasar el id de un tag html a una propiedad de un elemento polymer?

Tags: html5, polymer

Estoy empezando con esto de polymer y para ir aprendiendo cree una app Polymer2.0 que sirva como una especie de paginas amarillas.

1- Tengo este elemento `guiame-app` donde están las iron-pages definidas:

```
 <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="inicio" role="main">
     <guiame-inicio name="inicio"></guiame-inicio>
     <guiame-busq name="busqueda"></guiame-busq>
     <guiame-favs name="favs"></guiame-favs>
     <guiame-item name="item"></guiame-item>
     <guiame-g404 name="g404"></guiame-g404>
    </iron-pages>
```

2- Un segundo elemento `guiame-inicio` que tiene una lista de “accesos rápidos” o emergencias:

```
    <div class="card">
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Bomberos">
          <iron-icon id="bomb" icon="guiaIcons:whatshot" item-icon></iron-icon> Bomberos</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Farmacias">
        <iron-icon id="farm" icon="guiaIcons:local-hospital" item-icon> </iron-icon> Farmacias</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Policia">
        <iron-icon id="poli" icon="guiaIcons:local-taxi" item-icon> </iron-icon> Policia</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Hospital">
        <iron-icon id="hosp" icon="guiaIcons:local-pharmacy" item-icon> </iron-icon> Hospital</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Estado">
        <iron-icon id="est" icon="guiaIcons:location-city" item-icon> </iron-icon> Org. Estatales</paper-icon-item></a>
    </div>
```

3- Finalmente un elemento `guiame-item` de vista detallada que trae los datos desde un archivo JSON y muestra(debería mostrar) el item seleccionado al clickear en el link del elemento anterior:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">

<link rel="import" href="../src/guiame-icons.html">

<dom-module id="guiame-item">

    <template >
        <style>
         :host {
            display: block;

            padding: 16px;
        }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax auto url="../assets/emer.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">

        <iron-image src="[[item.imagen]]" sizing="cover" alt="[[item.imgAlt]]"></iron-image>
        <h1>[[item.nomb]]</h1>

        <paper-item>Dirección: [[item.dire]]</paper-item>

<!--itera por todos las ocurrencias del array tel -->
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.tel]]">
            <paper-button raised>
                <iron-icon icon="guiaIcons:phone"></iron-icon>[[item]]</paper-button>
            <p></p> 
        </template>
    </template>

</template>

<script>

    class guiameItem extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'guiame-item';
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                id: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                },
            };
        }

    }
        customElements.define(guiameItem.is, guiameItem);
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Todo este flujo de datos funciona(muestra datos del hospital, bomberos, policia, etc.) salvo que no puedo filtrar la lista del archivo JSON y mostrar solo el item en el que se clickeó en el elemento `guiame-inicio`.

¿Como puedo hacer para que el id de la etiqueta  en `guiame-inicio` se convierta en una propiedad del elemento `guiame-item` y por lo tanto se traiga solo la información de ese objeto en el archivo JSON?
Desde ya les agradezco lo que puedan aportar como solución a esto.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando un elemento `<iron-selector>` en tu elemento `<guiame-inicio>` puede resultar más sencillo:

```
<div class="card">
  <iron-selector selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="id">
    <div id="bomb"><iron-icon id="bomb" icon="guiaIcons:whatshot" item-icon></iron-icon>Bomberos</div>
    <div id="farm"><iron-icon id="farm" icon="guiaIcons:local-hospital" item-icon> </iron-icon>Farmacias</div>
    <div id="poli"><iron-icon id="poli" icon="guiaIcons:local-taxi" item-icon> </iron-icon>Policia</div>
    <div id="hosp"><iron-icon id="hosp" icon="guiaIcons:local-pharmacy" item-icon> </iron-icon>Hospital</div>
    <div id="est"><iron-icon id="est" icon="guiaIcons:location-city" item-icon> </iron-icon>Org. Estatales</div>
  </iron-selector>
</div>
```

selected sería una propiedad que tendrías que declarar en `<guiame-inicio>` y que podrías usar para enlazarla con `<guiame-item>`.

`<guiame-app>` quedaría entonces:

```
<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="inicio" role="main">
   <guiame-inicio name="inicio" selected="{{idSelected}}"></guiame-inicio>
    <guiame-busq name="busqueda"></guiame-busq>
    <guiame-favs name="favs"></guiame-favs>
    <guiame-item name="item" filtro="[[idSelected]]"></guiame-item>
    <guiame-g404 name="g404"></guiame-g404>
</iron-pages>
```

Comment: Estuve trabajando esta idea @jaslynx pero sigo con inconvenientes.  Al iron-selector tal como lo pusiste le agregué los tag `<a>` con los href para poder pasar de página, pero ahí enlazas con `selected="{{selected}}"` en vez de `idSelected` es un error de tipeo? porque aunque lo corrijo no me funciona; imprimo filtro en `guiame-item` y siempre está vacía. Gracias

Comment: ¿Has declarado la propiedad selected en el elemento `<guiame-inicio>`? En el apartado `static get properties()` tienes que declarar la propiedad selected de tipo String y con notify igual a true. De forma parecida tienes que declarar la propiedad filtro en el elemento `<guiame-item>`. En `<guiame-app>` puedes utilizar el nombre de identificador que desees para hacer el data binding entre guiame-inicio y guiame-item con tal que se denominen igual, no necesariamente se tiene que denominar idSelected.

Comment: Estaba declarada la propiedad, pero no estaba notify=true. Eso hizo la magia!!! Ahora no puedo hacer que se filtren los resultados, pero eso sería motivo de otra pregunta. Mil Gracias @jaslynx !